# Laravel Sociliate keeps asking for granted scopes

Tags: laravel, google-api, laravel-socialite

I'm using Laravel Socialite for oAuth2 with Google using this code:

```
return Socialite::driver('google')
    ->with([
        'access_type' => 'offline',
        'prompt' => 'consent',
        'include_granted_scopes' => 'false'
    ])
    ->scopes([
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage'
    ])
    ->stateless()
    ->redirect();
```

Yet every time the user logs into the app, it keeps asking for this scope, although the user has previously granted it.

How can I avoid re-asking for an already-granted scope?

Comment: Try removing the `'prompt' => 'consent'` line, I mean, you're telling google to ask for it every time.

Answer (score 1):

You have include_granted_scopes set to false which means it won't use the scopes already granted

And you are using prompt' => 'consent' which will force it to ask for consent everytime

I also can't see you using a refresh token so its probably going to ask anyway